# Concept of shape-shifting snakes in Hinduism

Tags: naga

Today, story of ichaadhari nagas and naagins are widely used in tv serials. In the content of one serial I read that this concept of shape-shifting snakes exists in Hindu scriptures. But I failed to find this concept in scriptures. Does this concept exists in Hinduism? Are snakes like Takshak, Vasuki, Adishesha etc. shape shifting snakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are thinking of, but in the Mahābhārata story of Nala and Damayantī, the snake Karkoṭaka bites Nala in order to temporarily disguise Nala with a different appearance, and Karkoṭaka himself takes on the form of Nala for the duration.  This is a kind of shape-shifting. (MBh 3.63.12: svarūpadhāriṇaṃ nāgaṃ dadarśa ca mahīpatiḥ)