# Is ShapeShifter Ability Discussed In Tantra Texts

Tags: tantra

Came across this question, as well as a few others, while perusing random HSE topics :

[Concept of shape-shifting snakes in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40732/concept-of-shape-shifting-snakes-in-hinduism/40804?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C30.1590#40804)

Do Tantras discuss being a shape-shifter as a supernatural ability type siddhi ? There is quite a bit of folklore with snakes for this, obviously, (all those Naagin tv shows and such.) However, beyond only snakes, I’m curious if shape-shifting as a specific thing is formally discussed in Tantra texts.

I asked a related question here but unfortunately didn’t receive answers : [Siddhi Of Assuming Any Form You Wish](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53230/siddhi-of-assuming-any-form-you-wish)